# Amazon EC2 : ephemeral volume isn't visible in new Instance I created

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an instance using an existing AMI (that I created from my Instance A), the problem is that the ephemeral volume isn't visible (df -i) in the new instance B even though I added it!

How can I display it and mount it to /mnt folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was from the "Kernel ID", I have to give to Instance A the same as Instance B, that will help someone else maybe.